# I want to set color of container from [43,43,12] but container takes only color(oxff....)

Tags: flutter

```
getColorFromUrl(url).then((color) {
print(color); // [R,G,B]  });
```

I want to make like this *Colour(43,43,12)*, without big brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are other constructors for the `Color` class

try

```
Color.fromRGBO(r, g, b, opacity)
```

and in your case it should be like

```
Color.fromRGBO(43, 43, 12, 1)
```

Comment: I unable to replace list tag [  ]

Answer (score 0):

You can make RGB Colors with `Color.fromARGB()`

You just specify four parameters with R being red, G being green and B being blue. While the a value and that's the alpha value and you set the transparency with it. 0 being transparent and 255 fully opaque.

In your case it would be: `Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0x43, 0x43, 0x12)`